# Drag a v-img to another application

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to make my image draggable in another application like google or another site would do. For example if I drop an image from google to a Word document, it will copy the link of it and some web applications would show the image instead; the behavior depends on the app.
But the problem is my v-img doesn't even print the link, it just does nothing.

Here is my code:

```
                  <v-card v-if="chunk.length >= i">
                        <template v-if="activeTab === 'Comments'">
                            <v-card-title class="justify-center">{{ chunk[i-1] }}</v-card-title>
                        </template>
                        <template v-else-if="activeTab === 'Images'">
                            <v-img
                                :src="getImgUrl(chunk[i-1])"
                                width="500"
                                contain
                                draggable="true"
                            />
                        </template>
                        <v-card-actions>
                            <v-col>
                                <v-btn
                                    color="#138ed3"
                                    block
                                    dark
                                > 
                                    Share
                                </v-btn>
                            </v-col>
                            <v-col>
                                <v-btn
                                    color="#ffcd00"
                                    block
                                    dark
                                >
                                    Save
                                </v-btn>
                            </v-col>
                        </v-card-actions>
                    </v-card>
```

As you can see I already tried the "draggable" option but it doesn't help.

Is there something I'm missing ?

Comment: Do you have a CodePen or CodeSandbox example?

Comment: Uh no I don't, but it's just a v-img into a v-card, pretty basic. That's why I don't understand why it's so difficult to do D:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with `v-img` is that it renders the image as background (using the CSS style `background-image`) rather than as an IMG tag. Apparently, CSS backgrounds do not support dragging.

Comment: Oh okay I see, very interesting ! Do you have an idea on how I could work around this ? Maybe I could use some css to change that ?

Comment: You can't - this is how VImg works in order to ensure lazy loading, a spinner and probably a gradient. Use native IMG tag if you need it to be draggable.